# How to convert xml with base64 to javabean?

Tags: java, xml

I want to convert following xml code to javaBean, i don't know how to deal with "dt:dt", can anyone help to resolve this?

```
<serialized_binary dt:dt="bin.base64" xmlns:dt="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:datatypes">
    JVBERi0xLjMKJaqrrK0KNCAwIG9iago8PCAvVHlwZSAvSW5mbw...
</serialized_binary>
```

Comment: Why do you want to deal with it? Take the base64, decode it, ignore the rest.

Comment: i'm using java to call an api while the request xml format is like this, so i need to convert and the interface can successfully decode this element.

Comment: You mean you don't want to convert this XML to JavaBean, you want to convert a JavaBean to this XML?

Comment: yes, but it's the same, i don't know how to define this element in java pojo, we use simple-xml-2.7.1. Maybe like this: @Element(name = "serialized_binary", required = true, data = true)
        @Namespace(reference = "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:datatypes", prefix = "dt")
        private ImageData imageData;

Comment: i accomplished, thanks.